# Reflection and ClassLoader in Java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I need add a class in my classpath after compile my program.

Then, I used the ClassLoader with Java Reflection, as the code below:

```
Class NewUnit;
Constructor constructor;

ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

// Define a class to be loaded.
String classNameToBeLoaded = "monarchs_project.Axe";

NewUnit = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);

constructor = NewUnit.getConstructor(int.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);

NewUnit newUnit  = (NewUnit) constructor.newInstance(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

The parameters of the Axe class are int.

But it doesn't work. The method getConstructor() not work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

int.class is not a valid class. You need to use the Type static variables in the wrapper classes in order to get a class object for a primitive type.  Your getConstructor call you should look like the following.

constructor = NewUnit.getConstructor(java.lang.Integer.TYPE, java.lang.Integer.TYPE, java.lang.Integer.TYPE, java.lang.Integer.TYPE);

Comment: The constructor is working now, but I can't create a instance of the class in newUnit object. IDE says:"Create NewUnit class in the project".

I solve this with this:

Object newUnit  = constructor.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);